# how to restrict registered user from trying to vote again

Tags: php

I'm very new to php coding and website designing.

I'm trying to develop an online voting system, where registered users only, are allowed to vote. I have done everything and it's working fine, but the help I need is after the user have logged out, how can I make the user not to be able to login again and vote twice? Or how I can I redirect the user the second time?

Comment: Save the user id on the database when he votes. That way, if he tries again check his user id against the database. If its already present do not allow him to vote again

Comment: you should be able to check the identity of the registered user (because he/she has to login in), so you can just store the vote info on the server and check against the stored info to see if the user has already voted.

Comment: Save the vote with the user ID and a timestamp. That way you can run a check during the voting process to ensure the user hasn't voted before.

Comment: Have tried that and I still get problem in the login part, can I get to see how you hold your exception in the login?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the user by taking the field in the database table. By applying the condition on that field at the time of login you will able to restrict the user who had already given the vote.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not that difficult to achieve if you had really had given a thought you would have seen how easy it is.

your users table must have a unique ID for the user to identify the user, then also on your table columns you need to have an enumerated field, you can call it `votingstatus` and set its default value to a, then when the user successfully casts a vote you then updated that field to `b`then you can look the the form controls for all users with `votingstatus = b` in that way you won't allow any one with `b` status to vote. when the user login you need to check the `votingstatus` if the user have `a` then allow login, if its `b` return appropriate message and deny access.

**Example table**

```
CREATE TABLE `voters` (
  `voter_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `id_number` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `voting_status` enum('a','b') DEFAULT 'a',
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Example casting a vote**

```
 <?php
try {


    $dbh->beginTransaction();


    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE candidates set votes = votes  + 1 where candidate_Id = ? ");

    if ($stmt->execute([$selectedvoter])) {

        $update = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE voters set voting_status = 'b' where voter_id = ?");
        $update->execute([$_SESSION['voter']]);

        $dbh->commit();

        echo  "<p class=\"alert alert-success\">Vote Casted</p>";


    }else{


        echo  "<p class=\"alert alert-danger\"> could not cast Vote</p>";

    }




}
catch (PDOException $e) {

    error_log("Error : " . $e->getMessage());

}
?>
```

**Login :**

```
try {

              $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT voter_id,id_number,password from voters where id_number = ? AND voting_status = 'a' ");
               $stmt->bindValue(1,$username);
               $stmt->execute();

               $results = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

               if(count($results) > 0){

                  foreach($results as $row){

                     if(password_verify($password,$row['password'])){


                        $SignError="<div class=\"alert alert-success\">
                        <button class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\">x</button>
                        Login Success. Redirecting...
                        </div>";

                        header("refresh:4;url=page.php"); // change page to ur dashboard url
                     }else{

                        $SignError="<div class=\"alert alert-error\">
                        <button class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\">x</button>
                        Password and ID number does not match
                        </div>";
                     }
                  }
               }else{

                   $SignError="<div class=\"alert alert-error\">
                  <button class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\">x</button>
                  Password and ID number does not match 
                  </div>";
               }

         } catch (PDOException $e) {

            error_log($e);
         }
```

The login code only allow voters with `voting_status = a` (meaning users who did not vote yet)

Comment: Please can you help me out with the login as well?

Comment: @DanielChuks updated. if this help you may upvote and mark the answer

Comment: Please I really need assistance. I tried it I still have an error. Do you mind send me your email so I can forward my code to you, I'm unable to upload the code here. I really need help. Its my final project for the school. Thanks..

Comment: masivuyecokile@gmail.com